# Mute first video for the length of a second video ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Hey guys so I'm making this command for ffmpeg which objective is to create a overlay of 2 videos and a couple images but now I need to mute the first video while the second one is playing. Would this be possible to do in ffmpeg in a single filter complex with out having to run ffmpeg to mute and then run it again for the overlays?

My current filter complex in case it helps understand what im doing

```
-filter_complex 
    "[0]crop='min(ih,iw)':'min(ih,iw)':'iw/2':'ih/2'[cropped];
    [1]trim=end_frame=1,
    geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':128:128,
    setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[mask];
    [1][mask]alphamerge[cutout];
    [cropped][cutout]overlay=x='{x}':y='{y}'[v];
    [0][1]amix=2[a]" 
    -map "[v]" 
    -map "[a]
```

Very resumed what Im looking for is a way to mute the first video for the total length of the second video and then unmute.

Comment: The filtergraph shows exactly one overlay and no time shift applied to the overlay, so the overlay input is active from the start of the main input. Did you want [sidechaincompress](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sidechaincompress)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple ideas. Both of which you need to know the start and end time of the overlay

1. Use [`asegment`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#segment_002c-asegment) and [`anullsink`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsink)

```
-filter_complex \
    ...
    [0]asegment=20[kill][keep]; \
    [kill]anullsink; \
    [keep]adelay=20000,[1]amix=2[a]"
```

2. Open the first video twice, first video only and second audio only.

Then set `-ss`/`-t`/`-to` on the audio-only input to only load what you want to hear, and use `adelay` filter to make the audio start at the time specified by `-ss` filter.

```
ffmpeg -an -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -ss 20 -vn -i video1.mp4 \
       -filter_complex ...;[2]adelay=20000:1,[1]amix=2[a] \
       ...
```

If video2 goes into the middle of the output video, you need to add another audio-only input for the second video1 audio segment.

2a. Use `-f concat` or `concat`

Using this idea of specifying input file multiple times, you can use various [stream concatenation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) methods.

3. Use [`asendcmd`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) and [`astreamselect`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#streamselect_002c-astreamselect)

```
-filter_complex \
  ...
  asendcmd='[0:a]asendcmd='20 astreamselect map 1', \ 
  [1:a]astreamselect=inputs=2:map=0[a]
```

Video2 placed in the middle of video1, you need to use `start-stop [enter] ..., [leave] ...` command for `asendcmd`.

Curious to see if others have a better solution.

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer its really well written, but its not working, probably cuz i miss interpreted set 2. Can you have a look and let me know whats wrong? I have setted up where the second and third videos are the ones that are the audio-only and video-only

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RPwQ5jqp

Comment: Each numbered suggestions are different approaches to do the same thing. So, you need to pick one that suites your taste the best (well, may have different speed too if that's important). Also, I arbitrarily picked the duration of video2 as 20 seconds and to be inserted at the beginning of the output video. You need to specify the actual number for these (if not sure how, edit your question to specify the video 2 duration and when it starts to play in output video.

Comment: Got it, Im using the 20 seconds for testing.
Using the option 1, I tried applying it but its running the video with out the 20 seconds i asegmented which is not what it should do i guess. In other words its not silincing it but cutting it out from what i hear in the final video.

Comment: What happens if you flip `[kill][keep]` to `[keep][kill]`?

Comment: I guess it works, kinda cuz now i dont have sound even after the 20 secs

Comment: Does video2 actually start at t=0 in the output video?

Comment: Yhe they start at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242520/discussion-between-deadsec-and-kesh).